# Extracting two pieces of data from one file and inserting them into two different places of a different file

Tags: text-processing, scripting

I have a file named `parse.txt` that contains the following 2 lines:

```
60

Moderate
```

I'm hoping to have a command in a bash script that will insert the `60` into line 7, column 17 of a new `final.txt` file, and insert the `Moderate` into line 8, column 53 also in the `final.txt` file.

Comment: Seems arbitrary.  Have you tried anything to accomplish this yet?  What delimits the columns in `final.txt`?

Comment: final.txt is in table format, with two of the "table columns" starting at column number 17, and the other column number 53.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with table format

Comment: I'm not sure table format was the right description, I guess what I'm trying to say is I understand how to copy things from one file to another on a particular line, but not sure how to insert this by column also.

Comment: How are the columns delimited?  With a space, a comma, a tab, something else?  I'm also confused by where you said that one of the columns starts at column 17.  Is it the first column or the 17th column?

Comment: Oh with spaces...so there will be a large gap of empty space between the inputs. I want to insert the 60 into line #7, column #17 a new final.txt file, and the Moderate into line #7, column #53 also in the final.txt file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this simple script:

```
#!/bin/sh
num=$(head -1 parse.txt)
val=$(tail -1 parse.txt)

# add 6 blank lines
for i in $(seq 6); do
  printf '\n' >> final.txt
done

# add 16 blank columns
for i in $(seq 16); do
  printf ' ' >> final.txt
done

# add num to line 7, column 17
echo $num >> final.txt

# add 52 blank columns
for i in $(seq 52); do
  printf ' ' >> final.txt
done

# add val to line 8, column 53
echo $val >> final.txt
```

So, for example, in vim, when selecting the value it will show: "final.txt" line 7 of 8 --87%-- col 17

Comment: Thanks, if I want them both in line 7, how would this be changed?

Comment: You would modify `echo $num >> final.txt` to prevent adding a new line via `printf $num >> final.txt` and then change `for i in $(seq 52); do` to `for i in $(seq $((36-${#num}))); do`

Comment: Did this sufficiently answer your question?

Comment: One lingering issue is I'm trying to add an additional piece of data to the same line in a different column...a 15 at column #60.  I tried out an additional   "for i in $(seq $((36-${#num}))); do"   but it forces the value on a new line, not the same line.

Comment: Because I need three pieces of data on the line, not two

Comment: I think I'm good to go now thanks

Comment: Yes, just modify the echo to be another printf at the end and use a similar loop for adding more spaces.  Great to hear it worked for you, would you mind accepting the answer if you're good to go?